# How many users can fit in one call with new Transactional Messaging API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

With the new transactional messaging API I can send out an email to multiple users with this call:

POST /messaging/v1/email/messages/

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sendMessageMultipleRecipients.htm

--> What is the maximum amount of users I can send to with this call? Is there a limit? Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't give a hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this REST API [doc:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)

> The maximum payload of any call is four megabytes.